# Kotlin Compose Search Bar

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have some doubts how to realize Search Bar in my Compose application. I call my `SeachView` function from `ContactContent` function where I pass `state` value.

```
@Composable
fun ContactContent(navigateToProfile: (Contact) -> Unit) {
    val contacts = remember { DataProvider.contactList }
    val textState = remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue("")) }
    Column(){
        SearchView(textState)
        LazyColumn() {
            items(
                items = contacts,
                itemContent = {
                    ContactListItem(contact = it, navigateToProfile)
                }
           ...
   }
```

In `SearchView` I not sure how should I call `onImeActionPerformed` search state as mine search state is not be recognized.

```
@Composable
fun SearchView(state: MutableState<TextFieldValue>) {
    Surface(){
        TextField(
            value = state.value,
            onValueChange = { value -> state.value = value},
            leadingIcon = {...},
            keyBoardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                keyboardType = KeyboardType.Text,
                imeAction = ImeAction.Search
            ),
            onImeActionPerformed = {action, softKeyboardController -> if (action == ImeAction.Search){
                >HERE IS WHERE I AM NOT SURE WHAT TO DO<
                DataProvider.newSearch(textState)
            }
     ...
}
```

**newSearch function snippet**

```
fun newSearch (textState: MutableState<String>){
val result = repository.search(
      token = token,
      page = 1,
      query = "chicken"
  )
  DataProvider.value = result
}
```

Maybe you have a different solution how to realize the search bar from the list with  with Kotlin Compose.

Comment: This is a question of how to get a text value from a text state? `textState.value.text`

Comment: Yes it is, but when i add it i do get '@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function' error in SearchView()

Comment: Show `DataProvider.newSearch` function

Comment: Sure, i have added newSearch function, do you need DataProvider object list as well?

Comment: You error looks like a typo, hard to say without the whole project..

Comment: Ok i will try to figure something out. But anyway thanks for the help, Dyakuyu @PhilipDukhov

Comment: In compose samples is an implementation of an advanced SearchBar maybe it helps to get some inspiration https://github.com/android/compose-samples/blob/main/Jetsnack/app/src/main/java/com/example/jetsnack/ui/home/search/Search.kt

Answer (score 1):

Do not use it directly in the parenthesis of the `onImeActionPerformed`, extract it in the parent Composable right before calling the `TextField`. Store it in a `val`, then use that val inside your `onImeActionPerformed`. Alogside, I assume you are creating that parameter with something like `() -> Unit`, ok so I'm not sure of this, but I think changing that to `@Composable () -> Unit`, you can access it directly without extracting it in a val first. Try it out